# Bootstrap button group inside vertical button group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

I'd like to create a vertical button group, containing a horizontal button group, and a few buttons inside. My attempt looks like this:

```
  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width : 60%">Row 1.1</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width : 40%">Row 1.2</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Row 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Row 3</button>
  </div>
```

I want button `Row 1.1` and `Row 1.2` to be in one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your button group in a `row` class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width : 60%">Row 1.1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width : 40%">Row 1.2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PoZpepN). You might wanna change the width/border the way you want it.

---

**EDIT**

As for the buttons not being rounded, here's the class responsible for it, you can change it:

```
.btn-group-vertical > .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

From `bootstrap.css`, the `btn` class has a `border-radius: 4px` :

```
.btn {
    ...
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

You can either remove all the radius or change the second button to have the same `border-radius`

New [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PoZpepN)

Comment: Lower edges of buttons in first row are rounded, while the upper edged of the button below them are not. This doesn't look good...

Comment: That's Bootstrap `btn` class. As I said, you might want to consider making some changes. Add some padding to your `btn-group` (`<div class="btn-group" style="padding:10px">`) to see that the buttons are rounded.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOEEjY I meant something more like this. Anyway, you showed me how to do it.

Comment: Exactly, the padding was just to show that bootstrap's `btn` class has a `border-radius`, which you can overwrite.